# I using compass for making Sprites of images then i m facing this error

Tags: rubygems

> ```
> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (7 for 6)
>
> Backtrace:
> /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_decoding.rb:120:in `decode_png_image_pass'
> /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_decoding.rb:120:in `decode_png_without_interlacing'
> /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_decoding.rb:99:in
> ```
>
> `decode_png_pixelstream'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_decoding.rb:81:in`
>   from_datastream'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/image.rb:74:in
>   `from_datastream'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_decoding.rb:45:in`
>   from_file'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:16:in
>   `block in construct_sprite'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:14:in`
>   each'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:14:in
>   `construct_sprite'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/sprite_methods.rb:57:in`
>   generate'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/sprites.rb:179:in
>   `sprite_url'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:143:in`
>   _perform'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in
>   `perform'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:397:in`
>   visit_prop'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`
>   block in visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`with_frame'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`
>   visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in
>   `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in`
>   map'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in
>   `block in visit_rule'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in`
>   with_environment'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in
>   `visit_rule'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`
>   visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in
>   `block in visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`block in with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:301:in`
>   block (2 levels) in visit_if'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:301:in
>   `map'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:301:in`
>   block in visit_if'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in
>   `with_environment'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:300:in`
>   visit_if'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`
>   block in visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`with_frame'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`
>   visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:304:in
>   `visit_if'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`
>   visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in
>   `block in visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`block in with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in`
>   block (2 levels) in visit_import'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in
>   `map'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in`
>   block in visit_import'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`with_frame'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in`
>   visit_import'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`
>   block in visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`with_frame'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in`
>   visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in
>   `block in visit_children'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in`
>   map'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in
>   `visit_children'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in`
>   block in visit_children'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in
>   `with_environment'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in`
>   visit_children'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `block in visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in`
>   visit_root'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in`
>   visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in
>   `visit'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in`
>   css_tree'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in
>   `render'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in`render'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:17:in
>   `block in render'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:29:in`
>   with_import_scope'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:16:in
>   `render'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:494:in`
>   update_stylesheet'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in
>   `block in update_stylesheets'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in`
>   each'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in
>   `update_stylesheets'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:473:in`
>   on_file_changed'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:331:in
>   `block in watch'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:252:in`
>   call'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:252:in
>   `on_change'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:290:in`
>   block in initialize_adapter'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:254:in
>   `call'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:254:in`
>   report_changes'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:323:in
>   `poll_changed_directories'
>       /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:299:in`
>   block in start_poller'
>       */
>       body:before {
>         white-space: pre;
>         font-family: monospace;
>         content: "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (7 for 6)"; }

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I could solve it by changing the version of chunky_png to 1.3.6:

```
gem uninstall chunky_png --version 1.3.8
gem install chunky_png -v 1.3.6
```

Here an overview of the versions of related packages (which works for me):

- sass (3.4.22)
- chunky_png (1.3.6)
- compass (1.0.3)

You can check your versions with:

```
gem list
```

Comment: Reinstalling ruby/compass fixed my problem. (Though I did not follow the steps you listed.) Thank you for the guidance!